# Why should mathematics not allow contradictions?

Tags: logic, paradoxes

**Heads up**.  I have no technical training in logic, nor have read any book about it.  This question is coming mostly from my intuition, so please consider giving me a reference --- I'm particularly interested in technical explanations to the fact that contradictions trivialize mathematics.

I'm trying to make sure that the following proof is correct and what it says for mathematics.  (In this question, whenever I say "mathematics", I mean the systems of logic that express mathematics.)

```
Theorem.  (P and ~P) implies Q.
Proof. Suppose P and ~P. Then

1    P                 detachment from P and ~P
2    ~~P               double negation
3    ~~P or Q          disjunction introduction
4    ~P implies Q      implication?
5    ~P                detachment from P and ~P
6    Q                 modus ponens
```

In other words, a contradiction implies anything at all.

**Question 1**. Is this why we cannot have contradictions in mathematical logic (and therefore in mathematics)?  Because --- as Eric Wolsey comments below --- sentential logic is a subset of predicate logic (and, perhaps I may add that mathematics is expressed by a predicate logic), then we may say that the theorem above says that if mathematics would have a contradiction, then anything at all would be implied by it.  (Apparently the answer to this question is "yes, the theorem above is correct and it is enough of a reason to say mathematics cannot allow a contradiction".

**Question 2**. I'm concerned with speaking nonsense here.  The relationship between these logic systems are not very clear to me, so my second question would be --- what book or paper would spell this result in particular?  I'd like to read the exposition of an expert.  (So this is a reference request.)

Comment: Do you know about paraconsistent logics?

Comment: Sentential logic is a subset of predicate logic.

Comment: I'm confused by Confusion 1 - because what you in fact proved is a theorem saying that starting from axioms $P, \neg P$ and applying rules of deduction you conclude $Q$.  If you want the _tautology_ $(P\land\neg P)\rightarrow Q$ you substitute all possible truth values of $P, Q$ and build a truth-table showing it always evaluates to true.

Comment: @Shaun, not any more than I know about more typical systems, but I heard once that they allow a contradiction.  Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @JohnDoe, your comment makes me a bit more confused.  It makes me feel that in sentential logic, theorems and tautologies are equivalent.  Anyhow, from Eric Wolsey's comment, I think my question is answered --- the theorem exposed by the question shows why mathematics cannot have contradictions.  (We'd be able to infer anything at all.)

Comment: Even if my question is already answered, I'd appreciate getting a book that somehow answers this question --- so I can see how experts answer the question.  (Thank you!)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the havoc that contradictions cause in mathematics." Proof by contradiction involves contradictions and produces many useful results. What kind of "havoc" is that? Perhaps you're thinking of the way mathematicians try to avoid constructing sets of axioms that lead to contradictions. Indeed, if you can prove a contradiction within some system, then you can prove anything in that system, including every statement and its negation. That leads to a very uninteresting result.

Comment: I rewrote that to "I'm particularly interested in technical explanations to the fact that contradictions trivialize mathematics." By "havoc" I had meant the trivialization of the system.  This little proof I wrote above, I have never seen it anywhere and I'm looking for a reference that explains such things.  I must be looking in the wrong places because the topic seems rather important --- although trivial?

Comment: @user1145880 You can call it "disjunction introduction."

Comment: Nice, @soupless!  That makes sense --- we're introducing a disjunction.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you have to exclude contradictions it's just that the systems which allow it aren't interesting. It's like allowing $0=1$, you can do it but $x=1x=0x=0$ so every number is $0$ and it's not interesting.

Comment: Some systems that allow contradictions *are* interesting, @CyclotomicField. Have a look into paraconsistent logics.

Comment: @Shaun Existence isn't particularly interesting. Solve a real problem with it then get back to me.

Comment: Paraconsistent logics are used to handle data corruption in binary codes, @CyclotomicField.

Comment: See [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/11663081.2019.1656393).

Comment: Paraconsistent logics turned out not to be useful. The reason why a contradiction is so fatal is the explosion principle. We can derive every statement from a contradiction , so a theory with a contradiction is completely useless.

Comment: But that's exactly the point of a paraconsistent logic, @Peter: the principle of explosion *doesn't* hold for them (*by definition*)! And they are useful. See above.

Comment: @Shaun No, they are not.

Comment: Is that peer-reviewed article not enough for you, @Peter?

Comment: @Shaun We do not need this kind of logic at all. No problem can be solved with this logic that cannot be solved as well with the "usual" logic. There is no reason to give up the "usual" logic.

Comment: That's a bit of a sweeping statement, @Peter. Please cite your sources.

Comment: @Shaun Apparently, you like  to have the last word. I have said my opinion (I am also not the only one with this opinion) and see no merit to continue this "discussion". You can again counter my comment , but I am out.